# How many components are there in graph?

Tags: math, graph, graph-theory, discrete-mathematics

A simple graph has vertices which are labeled between 2 and 120. There is an edge between two vertices of graph if `b = a*k` where `a, b` are vertices and `k` is any natural number. How many component does this graph have?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is not about programming indeed. I will still answer it because it is fairly easy:

All vertices with a prime number `> 60` will be alone, so: `61, 67,
71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 107, 109, 113`

Everything else will be connected to one component: The 2 will connect together all even numbers. And all prime numbers `<= 60` will connect to another even number by taking `k = 2`